# Multi Module Android Project Gradle suggestion

Tags: android, gradle, android-build-type, build-variant

I have a project A which has 3 B,C and D lib module. 
Project A has 4 builtTypes Debug, Staging, Beta and Release but library modules has only debug and release. Now if I want one of my lib module consider C to have 3 buildTypes Debug, Staging and release. How can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Go `View > Tool Windows > Build Variants`.

You can see all of modules with **BuildVariants** that are combination of `BuildTypes` and `ProductFlavors`, and select which type you want use for any module.

for example I define 2 flavors {`production`,`staging`} anly for `app` and `remote` modules and by default every module have 2 buildType named {`debug`,`release`}

[image: Build Variants Window]

and then you run app or install or build apk with selected configs